# Alternative for BIND method in sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, sansa

I am using [Sansa stack](http://sansa-stack.net/) to execute sparql queries on huge amount of data in HDFS .Sansa is a spark based framework that executes sparql queries on huge amount of data. My sparql query is  having an assignment as below in it .

```
BIND(STRAFTER(str(?d), "#") as ?docid) .
```

But sansa is not able to do this conversion and the final output does not have the variable ?docid .
Is there any other function similar to BIND available in sparql ?

Comment: You can implicitly bind function outcomes to variables in the SELECT clause:  `SELECT (STRAFTER(STR(?d), "#") as ?docid)`. But it seems unlikely to me that the problem is the `BIND` itself. I'm not familiar with Sansa stack or its SPARQL support, but are you sure the problem is the BIND operation and not, say, the `STRAFTER` operation? Or perhaps the reason you get no result is simply that `?d` is not bound to anything (or not bound to anything that has a '#' character in it). It's impossible to answer without a few more details.

Comment: Afaik, this feature isn't available yet, but might be in the next release. Moreover, I guess it's better to ask this question on their [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sansa-stack)